The Best Way to Build a Von-Neumann Replicator
What Von-Neumann replicator design is the most space and time efficient, in the fiction I'm working on, the civilization colonizes star systems by using interstellar ships to carry Von-Neumann replicators to them and dropping these replicators off on planets for them to grow.
But the size and replication speed of these machines matter, if they are too big, then they will not fit on the ships, if they replicate too slow, then it will take too long to fully colonize the star system and build things like a dyson sphere.
I have some designs candidates, the first one is a large machine called "Alchemy Engine", this machine is a industrial system with advaced production devices, like nuclear based atom shifters and photon-electrical-radiation catalyst based chemical constructers. It also has embedded nano-machines for self repair, replication, mining and more. The alchemy engines are really big, like over 1km tall and 300m in diameter, so they require gigantic vessel to transport them, but they can replicate really fast.
The second design is just nano-machines, they mines the resources and replicates, while using chemical, nuclear and light energy to power themselves, and can replicate much faster than ordinary cells.
The third design is life, by using a super population bomb to create intelligent life and build a civilization, this method is very slow and may not work.
The last design is a mix of second and third design, it is a seed that stores all genetic information of hundreds of thousands of species and some artificially enhanced genes in a compacted form, when planted, it will first use chemical and light energy to grow like a plant, while printing out inorganic machines with secretion of inorganic matter. With the machines, it will grow much faster and be capable of harnessing nuclear energy, and grow even faster, until it covers the entire planet. This might be one of the most compacted and advanced one, since it can not only replicate itself, but also create entire eco-system with diverse life, but it's environmental requirement is higher.
Without concepts like vacuum energy harvesting, what design of a replicator is the most space and time efficient, it's best to have the machine small enough for a landing pod or shuttle to carry and can build a dyson sphere in one or two centuries or less.

You're asking us to compare a range of insufficiently specified schemes (which are well beyond our real-world capability to produce) with unspecified performance for optimum performance against two variables with no weighting specified.  (How long is "too long" to build a dyson sphere around a targeted system?  How much required volume/mass on a transport vessel is "too much"?)  Unfortunately, by the time you specify the parameters enough for anyone else to answer, it will come down to a simple calculation that you can do yourself.

Frame Challenge
If your civilization is specifically colonizing new planets and systems, then this is going to be a relatively large-scale, resource intensive operation.
You are not going to be grabbing a few random ships here and and there and sending them off into the void... No.
You are going to be building vessels that are tailored, specifically to the task at hand.
Look at large-scale industry for example - we have things like Tunnel Boring Machines or the Space Shuttle Crawler or the BOKA Vanguard - these are all machines with a very specific purpose that are tailored to suit the needs of very big and complex tasks.
Rather than trying to cobble together existing machines to make it work - it is cheaper and more efficient in the long run to build a machine from scratch (even if that cost is hundreds of millions of dollars) to complete the task.
Your colonization efforts would absolutely fall under that category.
As such - the Size would be as large as they needed to be and for such a big machine, a space vessel would be designed to move it safely - just like the BOKA Vanguard was designed to move Oil Rigs (as well as capability to move other ships) - a specialist Craft (or class of crafts) would be designed to move your Replicator.
So - the size of your replicator is irrelevant - make it as large as you need it to be, then state that the Colonization craft is suitably specced to be able to carry it - as this is how it would be done in real life.

To make this work even better, make the ship completely automated. The ship being a large movable fabrication platform, manufacturing & seeding the terraforming machinery on site. After doing so, it collects a share of the resources harvested during the terraforming process, and it moves to the next destination along the line, to repeat the process. Kinda like Destiny from SGU. Having it create more new ships if it can obtain the resources would allow some Von-Neumann action.
